# iOS app works on simulator but not on real device

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I have read the other questions which are related to the same problem, but I am not getting the right answer... It just keeps getting me crazy.

I am developing an iOS app and it runs nice on the simulator provided by the Xcode IDE, but when I install it on my iPhone and run it, a white screen appears and the debugger stops the execution, showing me this error, with the signal SIGABRT:

```
dyld`__abort_with_payload:
    0x1000f5cd0 <+0>:  movz   x16, #0x209
    0x1000f5cd4 <+4>:  svc    #0x80
->  0x1000f5cd8 <+8>:  b.lo   0x1000f5cf0               ; <+32>
    0x1000f5cdc <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-16]!
    0x1000f5ce0 <+16>: mov    x29, sp
    0x1000f5ce4 <+20>: bl     0x1000f5500               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x1000f5ce8 <+24>: mov    sp, x29
    0x1000f5cec <+28>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #16
    0x1000f5cf0 <+32>: ret
```

The app does not request anything (access to something, network calls, etc...), it just draws some custom views without any special feature.

What's the meaning of that? I have run other apps of my own on my iPhone and all of them worked nice.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I always clean the project, check the trust this developer on my phone, reboot my phone, delete the App on my phone, check the state of my project, clear temporary cache folders from xCode and then continue searching stack overflow when I get this kind of issue. This one seems different then the ones I have received though.

Comment: What is the app trying to do when it starts up? Is it requesting permission, making network calls, etc. The above trace is not much of a help.

Comment: Also, make sure you're not doing something that is reliant on macOS specific behavior. For example, macOS drives are often not case sensitive, whereas the physical device is, so if the capitalization doesn't match, it might not be finding some resource that is successfully found on simulator. I don't think we'll be able to easily diagnose this on the basis of the information provided. A stack trace or full crash log might be helpful.

Comment: Ok I will try to edit the question in order to give more information... By the way, @CodeBender, the app is not requesting anything, it just shows up some simple views.

Comment: We don't have nearly enough information to figure out what's going on.  A SIGABRT will nearly always log information to the console: can you post what was logged?

Comment: Also, when the app crashes, can you type `bt` and press Enter at the `(lldb)` prompt and paste the output here?  Thanks!

Comment: That log doesn't help. Show code from your `viewDidLoad` of the first view shown. Show code from your AppDelegate - didFinishLaunching method.

Comment: I had similar issue after moved to Xcode 8..In my case it was a code signing issue and i fixed by validate code signing.Worth to mention,when i had this issue.still i can able to open app from iPhone after installed(after crash)..I am not sure error could come from your code.if you update your post with your code will helps to resolve issue...

Comment: Try  adding exception breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that your project like to library that only provide x86 binary?

Comment: How to make the iOS device to read y86 binary? because I am facing the same issue, runs on simulator but not on iOS device.